# A "house" (pentagon) with square height $x$ and triangle height $\frac12x$...

Tags: geometry

Imagine a simple drawing of a "house," a triangle with half of the height of a square that it's laying on, to form a pentagon. If the square's height is $x$ and the triangle's height is $\frac12x$ then the total area is $\frac54x^2$. What is the area of the largest upside down "house" that could fit inside? I *think* the answer is $0.703125x^2$, or $\frac{45}{64}x^2$, but I don't quite remember. Can someone show me how to get this? Thanks.

Comment: No one can help me?

Comment: Can you help yoursrlf by showing us how you arrived at your guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer of $\frac{45}{64}x^2$ is right.

It's clear that the area of the inside house is maximised when its floor touches the outer roof, and its roof touches the outer floor.

[image]

Summing amounts horizontally, we see

$$x=y+2d\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)$$

Summing amounts vertically, we see

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dfrac{3x}{2} &=& \dfrac{3y}{2} + (\dfrac{x}{2}-d) \\
\therefore\quad 3y &=& 2x+2d \\
&=& 2x+(x-y) \qquad\qquad\text{from (1)} \\
\therefore\quad y &=& \dfrac{3x}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Therefore the area of the inner house is

\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& \dfrac{5y^2}{4} \\
&=& \dfrac{5(3x/4)^2}{4} \\
&=& \dfrac{45}{64}x^2.
\end{eqnarray*}